# Analyzing the effect of terms on the continuation of an on-line discussion

Tags: statistical-significance, conditional-probability, natural-language, social-science

**The Data**

I am analyzing approximately 200 million online "threaded" posts (think USENET NEWS, Google Groups, Reddit, etc.). The posts have a tree structure like so:

```
  +-B---E     +-J
  |           |
A-+-C---F---H-+-K---L
  |
  +-D---G---I
```

Where `B`, `C`, and `D` are replies to `A`, `J` and `K` are replies to `H`, etc.

I have created a data set that considers each post as a member of one linear "thread" of one conversation. For example, post `H` has `3` parent posts [`F`, `C`, `A`], and three child posts [`J`, 'K`,`L`]. The number of parents is the post's depth. Therefore my data table looks like this:

```
+----+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|    |       |         |          |             |             |  any >= current |
| id | depth |  had    |  num of  | this had    | parent had  |    post had     |
|    |       |children | children | search term | search term | had search term |
+----+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  A |     0 |       1 |       11 |           0 |           0 |               0 |
|  B |     1 |       1 |        1 |           0 |           0 |               0 |
|  C |     1 |       1 |        5 |           0 |           0 |               0 |
|  D |     1 |       1 |        2 |           0 |           0 |               0 |
|  E |     2 |       0 |        0 |           0 |           0 |               0 |
|  F |     2 |       1 |        4 |           1 |           0 |               1 |
|  G |     2 |       1 |        1 |           0 |           0 |               0 |
|  H |     3 |       1 |        3 |           0 |           1 |               1 |
|  I |     3 |       0 |        0 |           0 |           0 |               1 |
|  J |     4 |       0 |        0 |           0 |           0 |               1 |
|  K |     4 |       1 |        1 |           1 |           0 |               1 |
|  L |     5 |       0 |        0 |           0 |           1 |               1 |
+----+-------+---------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Where `depth` is the number of parent posts, `had children` is 1 if the post had any children, 0 if not, `num of children` is the number of children (when this is 0, `had children` is 0, otherwise 1), `this had search therm` is 1 if one or more occurrences of the search term were found in the post, 0 otherwise, `parent had search term` is the same but for the directly proceeding parent if any, and `any >= current...` is 1 if the current post or any parent post had the search term.

*Note 1:* I am doing this for approximately 150 terms or groups of terms, but am asking for advice on any one single search.

**The Objective**

I would like to know if the presence of a term (or set of terms) has a statistically significant effect on the presence of children (does it increase the probability of the conversation continuing or decrease it?).

*Note 2:* With roughly 200M posts I am analyzing only the first 115 depths which, given the data set, all have a minimum of 100 posts with and 100 without the search term so that N for each depth is at least 200.

**Methods**

For each depth, I treat the mean value for `had children` as the probability that a post at the given depth would have children. I do this per depth because the probability of children changes non-linearly with depth[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSBQv.png). I compare the mean `had children` for posts with the search term to the mean `had children` of posts without; however, the presence or absence of the search term in the parent seems to also potentially influence outcomes.

To do this, I do a simple mean comparison at each (using python's `scipy.stats.ttest_ind()` and a Bonferroni corrected confidence value for 0.99[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Lye.png))

For plotting, I am plotting depth on the x-axis and % seen on the y-axis and corresponding +/- standard error or the mean (inner shading) and the confidence interval for 0.999:

[image: Example plot of % seen vs. depth for a given search term.]

**Questions**

1. Does this approach seem sound for determining if the presence or absence of some search terms (e.g., vulgar/insulting vs. laudative/encouraging) have a statistically significant effect on the continuation of a discussion? If no, what are your concerns or suggestions?
2. Is it necessary to identify and regress out confounders (e.g., the depth effect or the 2-person-conversation-effect [see footnote 2) for this to be meaningful?
3. What other considerations do you think are important?

**Footnotes**
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSBQv.png) The probability of children (both presence and number) for any post goes down from depths 0 to 1, then goes up for all data sets I have. It appears that this is almost exclusively due to two posters continuing a discussion. See figure:

[image: Example plot of children vs. depth]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Lye.png) I chose the ultra-strict Bonferroni correction because for the terms I am most interested in, the significance seems to survive given the sample size. I will probably relax it a bit for some less polarizing terms.